# the best way to get uniform behavior for dense and sparse array?

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

For example, in the following operation, you get different variable types and dimension shapes for normal array or matrix. This is a bit annoying. I am writing a function that accepts either array or sparse array for the universal operation. Besides just its sparsity and convert it to dense array ahead of time, is there any better way to get the same variable type and dimension shape?

```
In [41]: a = np.array([[0,1],[1,0]])

In [42]: b = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(np.array([[0,1],[1,0]]))

In [43]: np.sum(a>0, axis=0) / a.shape[0]
Out[43]: array([0.5, 0.5])

In [44]: np.sum(b>0, axis=0) / b.shape[0]
Out[44]: matrix([[0.5, 0.5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [162]: b                                                                                                  
Out[162]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [163]: b.A                                                                                                
Out[163]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

`sum` with axis of a sparse matrix produces a dense `matrix`, which by definition is 2d

```
In [164]: b.sum(axis=0)                                                                                      
Out[164]: matrix([[1, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

`keepdims` can be used to retain the 2d shape in the array case:

```
In [165]: a.sum(axis=0)                                                                                      
Out[165]: array([1, 1])
In [166]: a.sum(axis=0, keepdims=True)                                                                       
Out[166]: array([[1, 1]])
```

However `sum` for sparse does not accept the `keepdims` parameter:

```
In [167]: b.sum(axis=0, keepdims=True)                                                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-167-3e16df6729bd> in <module>
----> 1 b.sum(axis=0, keepdims=True)

TypeError: sum() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keepdims'
```

Alternatively you could remove the extra dimension from the `b` sum:

```
In [169]: b.sum(axis=0).A1                                                                                   
Out[169]: array([1, 1], dtype=int64
```

Off hand I can't think of a expression that works equally well for `a` and `b`.  A `sparse.issparse(a)` test is probably required.

`scikit-learn` adds some sparse utilities,

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f6924/sklearn/utils/sparsefuncs.py